# Xcode autocomplete & autocompiler is frozen, typing is laggy?

Tags: xcode

In one of my existing Xcode Projects, XCode autocomplete & autocompiler is frozen and the typing is laggy.
Autocomplete simply does not start, the autocompiler which will inform you if your code is incorrect with yellow/red bars from the right never appear, and typing feels a bit slow.

[Here is a video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1efcPY-dOOJdi202EvJ17YPKlmysTREEZ/view?usp=sharing) demonstrating. Interestingly, if you watch to the end, the autocomplete for super.viewDidLoad happens very quickly, even though it's frozen on the subclass...

This seems to happen primarily within a UIKit subclass (UIViewController, UIView). The lag & freeze does not seem to exist at the highest level. It also exists, sometimes, within individual functions in those classes, accessing particular properties.

When I create a brand new Xcode Project, the autocomplete is smooth as it should be.

I've tried reinstalling Xcode, rebooting my computer, clearing all unecessary cache data for Xcode & the project & that hasn't helped. I'm using Xcode 15 stable.

I thought it could be extensions I have to UIViewController. I have about 15 UIViewController extensions. Most add an additional function, and a few of them add conformance to protocols or classes. However, when I added these extensions to the fresh new project, I didn't get any lagging. Plus, these issues occur for many other types of classes as well.

Any ideas of what this could be?